# getting error with learn python the hard way exercise 14

Tags: python

I am following zed shaw's learn python the hard way and am following exercise 14. Here's the program I am talking about:

```
from sys import argv

script, user_name = argv
prompt = '> '

print "Hi %s, I'm the %s script." % (user_name, script)
print "I'd like to ask you a few questions."
print "Do you like me %s?" % user_name
likes = raw_input(prompt)

print "Where do you live %s?" % user_name
lives = raw_input(prompt)

print "What kind of computer do you have?"
computer = raw_input(prompt)

print """
Alright, so you said %r about liking me.
You live in %r.  Not sure where that is.
And you have a %r computer.  Nice.
""" % (likes, lives, computer)
```

Now, I run this program in powershell terminal using the command

```
python e:\python\ex14.py
```

and I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "e:\python\ex14.py", line 3, in (module)
script, user_name=argv
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack.
```

Now, I am not sure what the problem is. The only reason could be that I am typing the file path instead of typing the filename only.

Comment: If your goal is to learn Python, I'd recommend you try a more traditional tutorial.

Comment: could you provide a link to a more traditional tutorial?
I am new at this and was just following a few recommendations from this site. So far, I like this tutorial but would love to see a traditional tutorial too.

Comment: @agf How is _Learn Python the Hard Way_ not a traditional tutorial?

Answer (score 3):

This script expects to take an argument at the command line. You're not providing one.

At the terminal, type `python e:\python\ex14.py YourNameHere`.

Comment: Wow! It worked!
But I am unable to understand the reason why this happened
or which line in the program is making this happen.
Can you shed some light on this?

Comment: `sys.argv` is a list that contains all arguments passed to the Python interpreter at the command line, starting with the script name. `script, user_name = argv` assigns the first element of `argv` to `script` and the second to `user_name`. When you ran it without an argument, there was no second element, so you got a runtime error.

Comment: `user_name = argv` If you are learning Python as first language, I would recommend a tutorial that explains what `argv` and `argc` mean.

Comment: hmm, I think I get it. Will have to learn a little more about the argv command though. 
Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Nunoxic There is no `argc` in Python. It's not needed, since Python lists (unlike C arrays) know their own length.

Comment: I know. What I mean is these are fairly low level instructions which are really important in "real world" programming. If the author doesn't attempt to explain them well, I'd want to move to another tutorial.

Comment: could you point me to a tutorial which explains all these things in detail?